# Try/except if an element of a list exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, try-except

**The problem**

I have the following list in Python 3.6

```
Piko = {}
Piko['Name']='Luke'
```

I am trying to write a function that give the value of the element if it exist and is set and give `None` otherwise.
For example:

- INPUT: `isset(Piko['Name'])` OUTPUT: `Luke`
- INPUT: `isset(Piko['Surname'])` OUTPUT: `None`

**What I have tried**

1st try; based on my know how:

```
def isset1(x):
    try:
        x
    except KeyError:
        print(None)
    else:
        print(x)
```

2nd try; based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11786240/1008588) answer:

```
def isset2(x):
    try:
        t=x
    except IndexError:
        print(None)
```

3rd try; based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16154204/1008588) answer:

```
def isset3(x):
    try:
        x
    except Exception:
        print(None)
    else:
        print(x)
```

Any one of the previous gives me `KeyError: 'Surname`' error and does not output `None` as I wanted. Can anybody help me explaining how could I manage correctly the `KeyError`?

Comment: the arguments are evaluated _before_ entering the function so it's just not possible. Using `get` method seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: For reference: python dictionary [get](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm) method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Piko.get('Surname')

Piko.get('Surname', None)
```

are identical and return `None` since "Surname" is not in your dictionary.

For future reference you can quickly discover this from the Python shell (eg ipython) by typing:

> In[4]: help(Piku.get)

Which produces:

> Help on built-in function get:
>
> get(...)
>
> D.get(k[,d]) -> D[k] if k in D, else d.  d defaults to None.

Answer (score 3):

The exception is happening before it even gets into your `isset` function. When you do this:

```
isset(Piko['Name'])
```

… it's basically the same as doing this:

```
_tmp = Piko['Name']
isset(_tmp)
```

No matter what code you put inside `isset`, it's not going to help, because that function never gets called. The only place you can put the exception handling is one level up, in the function that calls `isset`.

Or, alternatively, you can not try to lookup `dict[key]` to pass into `isset`, and pass the dict and the key as separate parameters:

```
def isset(d, key):
    try:
        print(d[key])
    except KeyError:
        print(None)
```

But at this point, you're just duplicating `dict.get` in a clumsier way. You can do this:

```
def isset(d, key):
    print(d.get(key, None))
```

… or just scrap `isset` and do this:

```
print(Piko.get('Name', None))
```

Or, since `None` is the default if you don't specify anything:

```
print(Piko.get('Name'))
```